# Meteor method returns undefined to the client (asynchronous)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous, meteor

I've been working on integrating Google Recaptcha into a Meteor and AngularJS web application. Everything was smooth sailing until I had to validate the recaptcha response -- for some bizarre reason, I can't get an async response from the backend to the frontend.

I've tried a lot of different variations and have read many, many posts on SO and the internet in general, but with no luck -- so I opted to post my own question.

---

Here's what I'm doing:

**Client:**

```
Meteor.call('recaptcha.methods.validateRecaptcha', { 'response' : this.recaptcha.getResponse(this.id) }, function(error, result) {
    // error and result are both undefined
    console.log('Do something with the ' + error + ' or ' + result + '.');
}
```

So, I'm calling a Meteor method and passing in a callback that is run when the method is done. However, the `error` and `result` parameters are both undefined.

**Server:**

```
run: function(data) {
    if (this.isSimulation) {
        /*
         * Client-side simulations won't have access to any of the
         * Meteor.settings.private variables, so we should just stop here.
         */
        return;
    }

    return Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.post)(_someUrl, _someOptions);
}
```

That last line is a shortened version of the sync/async structure that I've found in several Meteor guides (I also tried this version), namely:

```
var syncFunc = Meteor.wrapAsync(HTTP.post);
var result = syncFunc(Meteor.settings.private.grecaptcha.verifyUrl, _options);
return result;
```

I've also tried a version using Futures:

```
var Future = Npm.require( 'fibers/future' );
var future = new Future();
var callback = future.resolver();
HTTP.post(Meteor.settings.private.grecaptcha.verifyUrl, _options, callback);

return future.wait();
```

---

Now, the intention here is that I use `Meteor.call()` to call this method from the client, the client-side stub runs (to prevent simulation errors since we use private `Meteor.settings` variables in the real non-SO server-side code) and returns immediately (which happens), and the server hits Google's Recaptcha API (which happens and the server receives a response) before returning the result to the client (which doesn't happen -- the callback occurs but with no error/success data).

My thought is that one of two things are happening:

1. I'm just doing something wrong and I'm not properly sending the data back to the client.
2. The synchronous client stub (which returns immediately) is telling the client that the server response isn't important, so it never waits for the proper asynchronous response.

Could any of the Meteor gurus weigh in here and let me know what's going on and how to get async requests to play nicely in a Meteor application?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the complete Meteor method on the server side? There's more to it than just `run: function (data) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call) for `HTTP.call`, which is the generic version of `HTTP.post`, it says

> Optional callback. If passed, the method runs asynchronously, instead of synchronously, and calls asyncCallback. On the client, this callback is required.

So, on server, you can run it asynchronously like this

```
run: function(data) {
    if (this.isSimulation) {
        /*
         * Client-side simulations won't have access to any of the
         * Meteor.settings.private variables, so we should just stop here.
         */
        return;
    }

    // No need to pass callback on server.
    // Since this part is not executed on client, you can do this
    // Or you can use Meteor.isClient to run it asynchronously when the call is from client.
    return HTTP.post(Meteor.settings.private.grecaptcha.verifyUrl, _options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This was actually my very first attempt at getting it working (before all the ```Meteor.wrapAsync()``` and futures business) -- but the client still receives no error/success data.

Comment: @SamuelMS: When you console log the result on the server, what are you seeing in the server console. Lets say you want to execute it asynchronously on server and console.log in the callback, are you getting error or result? From what I can see, your `wrapAsync` and `Future` stuff is also correct. I can only think of `HTTP.post` successfully getting called but no data is being returned to you.

Comment: I get a response from the HTTP -- the server is POSTing correctly and receiving the expected result (success/fail with appropriate inputs). It really seems to be an issue of getting the result back to the client.

Comment: @SamuelMS Sorry, I also don't have any other suggestions. If you find an answer, please post it here, so that it will be helpful for others. :)

Comment: No sweat, thanks for taking the time to look into this -- I especially appreciate the feedback on the futures/wrapAsync syntax since more eyes on it reduce the chances of it just being a simple mistake.

Comment: Okay, this is embarrassing -- after taking a break and coming back with fresh eyes, it looks like you actually hit the nail on the head with this answer. I was passing a callback on the server since I wanted to do extra work there as well, which you can't do if you want the client-side callback to run as well. My final solution used futures to wrap the HTTP callback, and resolve its promise when all extra work was done. Thanks again!

Comment: @SamuelMS a typical programmer's life :). It happens to me all the time as well. A small break always helps us. :). Thanks for taking time to explain what actually happened.